# Braintree payment with Paypal doesn't connect with my Paypal account

Tags: php, paypal, payment, braintree

I have been working with the implementation of Braintree payment gateway and now i am stuck with its Paypal method. The issue is describe below.

I have integrated the necessary code for for this and when selection the Paypal method and trying to login to Paypal, it always shows the error like below screenshot.
[![error screen while login in to paypal][1]][1]

I think this is happening because of the client token is wrong. but i have creating the token using the php method: $clientToken = Braintree_ClientToken::generate().

(It will currently login when i give the demo client token provided by Braintree demo code).

Here below i mentioned my code . Please check and hope anyone can trigger the issue.

```
<?php
require_once '_environment.php';

function braintree_text_field($label, $name, $result) {
    echo('<div>' . $label . '</div>');
    $fieldValue = isset($result) ? $result->valueForHtmlField($name) : '';
    echo('<div><input type="text" name="' . $name .'" value="' . $fieldValue . '" /></div>');
    $errors = isset($result) ? $result->errors->onHtmlField($name) : array();
    foreach($errors as $error) {
        echo('<div style="color: red;">' . $error->message . '</div>');
    }
    echo("\n");
}

// CLIENT TOKEN
$clientToken = Braintree_ClientToken::generate();

if(isset($_POST['payment_method_nonce'])){   
    $nonce  = $_POST['payment_method_nonce'];
    $result = Braintree_Transaction::sale(array(
      'amount' => '91.00',
      'paymentMethodNonce' => $nonce
    ));
    if ($result->success) {
        echo($result->customer->id);
        echo($result->customer->creditCards[0]->token);
        echo 'success';
    } else {
        foreach($result->errors->deepAll() AS $error) {
          echo($error->code . ": " . $error->message . "\n");
        }
    }    
}

?>
<form id="checkout" method="post" action="">
  <div id="payment-form"></div>
  <input type="submit" value="Pay $10">
</form>

<script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/v2/braintree.js"></script>
<script>
    var clientToken = '<?php echo trim($clientToken);?>';
    braintree.setup(clientToken, "dropin", {
        container: "payment-form"
        });
</script>
```

Comment: I work as a developer at Braintree. Are you running this in your Sandbox test environment or your production environment? It should work without issues in the Sandbox environment, but you may need to adjust your account configuration if you are in production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a PayPal transaction, you will need a customer id, the following sample works for me.

> index.php

```
<?php
require("config.php"); //config.php contains Braintree_Configuration object.

$aCustomerId = '39538986'; // can be generated from braintreegateway.com vault->New Customer
$clientToken = Braintree_ClientToken::generate(array(
    "customerId" => $aCustomerId
));
;
?>




<script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/v2/braintree.js"></script>
<script>
var clientToken = "<?php echo $clientToken ?>";
braintree.setup(clientToken, "dropin", {
  container: "payment-form"
});
</script>

<form>
    <div id="paypal-container"></div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
braintree.setup(clientToken, "paypal", {
  container: "paypal-container",

  onPaymentMethodReceived: function (obj) {
   window.location.href = 'http://localhost/braintree/checkout_paypal.php?nounce='+obj.nonce;
  }
});
</script>
```

> checkout_paypal.php

```
<?php
require("config.php");
$nonce = $_GET["nounce"];
$result = Braintree_Transaction::sale(array(
  'amount' => '100.00',
  'paymentMethodNonce' => $nonce,
  'options' => array(
    'submitForSettlement' => True
  )
));

?>
```